# Returning indexes of pairs of values

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of numbers and a number b and will print the indexes of all pairs of values in the list that sum to b. My code so far includes the list operations

```
def pairSum(a,b):
    for i in a:
        for j in a:
            if i+j==b:
```

it should run like this

```
>>>pairSum([7,8,5,3,4,6], 11)
0 4
1 3
2 5
```

Note that it returns the positions of the values in the list and not the actual numbers and this is what I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: This is usually referred to as two sum problem. Googling for two sum will give you a lot of explanations and solutions to the problem.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it does not print or return anything.

Comment: I am aware of this. My problem is in returning the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`

```
for i, x in enumerate(a): #i is index of x
    for j, y in enumerate(a[i+1:], start=i+1): #j is index of y
        if x+y == b:
            print(i, j)
```

The `a[i+1:]` is to prevent duplicates and to stop values from being added to themselves.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped. I feel silly not thinking about enumerate.